# Is it mandatory of using 3 tier archeticture while using Entity FrameWork?

Tags: .net, asp.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a web application where i need to use entity frame work.Actually i came to know that Entity follows 3 layered model.So is it mandatory to use again 3 layered model while using entity?Can any give your valuable idea's and link's regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity framework will create a `DAL only`. If you want to remove the Business logic layer you can.But working in a `3 Tier` is a better option,which is easy to maintain

Comment: yes for Business Logic you need to design. Where you write all the business logic

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET contains EntityDataSource so you can talk to EntityFramework directly from ASP.NET markup without any business layer. Than it is more about "layering" and what you call a layer. Btw. there is difference between layer and tier. Layer is logical and tier is physical (different process or computer).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can do pretty much what you want with it.

With the current info you posted and seem to be handling, its very hard to say anything else on it.

I suggest you look more into what you are going to do, and if you are concerned with the design aspects try to get someone involved in your project that can help you start on the right track.